# Erro numa SQL sintax - mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

Estou com um erro de sintaxe no meu código, porém não consigo encontrar qual é o meu o erro.
Esse é o erro que estou recebendo:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `categoria`= 'hidrossanitario'' at line 1

Meu código:

```
$teste=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$id);
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `downloads`  order by datacadastro DESC  where `categoria`= '".$teste."'";
```

Já procurei em vários lugares e a resposta mais próxima para o meu problema que encontrei, foi colocar o `$teste` da forma como já coloquei no código acima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue o bloco, colocando primeiro os termos de busca, e só depois deves especificar a forma como os queres apresentar.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_ ORDER BY campo1 ASC
```

Esta tua consulta *SQL* pode ser escrita de várias, formas, apesar de existirem métodos mais adequados para cada situação.

Nesta primeira forma, simplesmente quebra-se as aspas, e introduz-se a variável onde deve estar:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `downloads` where `categoria`= '".$teste."' order by datacadastro DESC";
```

Podes também interporlar a strng, escrevendoa variável dentro de chavetas `{}`:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `downloads` where `categoria`= '{$teste}' order by datacadastro DESC";
```

Existem ainda várias outras formas de escrever uma consulta *SQL*.

Se a variável teste for um inteiro *(int)* recomendo que a escrevas sem as aspas simples *('').*

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema está no select, acho que o order by tem que está depois da cláusula where:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `downloads` where `categoria`= '".$teste."' order by datacadastro DESC";
```